# Multi-dimensional arrays -- getting the same coding power as 1-dimensional arrays

Tags: .net, arrays

I mostly program in C# but this seems to apply to all of .NET.

I'm in a situation where using multi-dimensional arrays seems like the most logical thing, but I feel like I'm locked out of the power of .NET by using them.

- `System.LINQ` doesn't work with multi-dimensional arrays. (ETA: But see Nico Schertler's comment)
- `System.Array`'s utility methods are very limited in what they can do with a multi-dimensional array.
- <strike>There doesn't seem to be any way to write extension methods for a multi-dimensional array.</strike> (ETA: This is wrong, see Nico Schertler's comment)
- A few years ago, multi-dimensional arrays were much slower -- is this still the case?
  [Why are multi-dimensional arrays in .NET slower than normal arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468832/why-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-net-slower-than-normal-arrays) (ETA: Yes, see Tim S's answer)

I know I have the option to use flattened arrays, but that doesn't really match the data. I also know I have the option to just loop over all the dimensions and copy, but that seems such an ancient way to do things when the language and compiler are intelligent. So my questions are:

- Is there a standard way to use LINQ (or equivalent functionality) with multi-dimensional arrays (cast a 2-D array into a database or `List<Tuple>`)?
- Is there a standard way to slice up a multi-dimensional array (return a single hypersurface, or a range of hypersurfaces)?
- Sorting. I found [C# rectangular array sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291568/c-sharp-rectangular-array-sort/) ; but that doesn't really apply since I do know the dimensions ahead of time.

ETA: I'm specifically talking about the "native" array type that's declared `double[,] dataTable = new double[5,3];` in C#, not jagged arrays, or any other nested class.

Comment: You *can* write extension methods for multi-dimensional arrays. E.g. I recently implemented `IEnumerable<double> Linearize(this double[,] arr)`. And with such an extension method you can use most common LINQ methods without *much* overhead.

Comment: @Nico you can do that but you have to write a separate extension method for each rank. There's no way to write a single extension method that works for all ranks.

Comment: How come this question was not immediately closed as opinion-based? Is it possible to answer this with (non-arbitrarily chosen) facts?

Comment: @usr because I am asking specific questions about specific problems I am having. Nico answered one of them in the comment, how to integrate LINQ with multi-dimensional arrays. the "opinion" questions are just me venting my frustration.

Comment: @AnotherParker I advise you to make very clear in the question what you're asking and to remove anything opinion-based. So far I stand by my close vote (opinion-based). For your second subquestion I'd still close as too broad. I appreciate the spirit of the question but I believe it is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: The CLR is not optimized for MD arrays although that clearly would possible. Why? In my experience MD arrays are very rare. I'd rather have really fast SZ arrays and slow MD arrays than both equally fast. Why invest money into a feature area that is *very* rarely used? I just grepped 150 KLOC of code driving production websites and the only place I could find an MD array was in the code for levenshtein distance.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful information. But I'm not as concerned about speed of operation (my arrays are small enough that the time difference is insignificant) but about coding style, readability, maintainability, extendibility.

Answer (score 2):

They are *very* awkward data structures.  In any language, not just C#.  Some of the inherent problems with them:

- There is no meaningful way to iterate them.  The order is inherently ambiguous, no way to signal that a new dimension starts iterating.  This is what kills their use in Linq.
- Calculating the address of an element is inherently expensive.  An N-dimensional array requires N-1 multiplications and N length lookups and bound checks to find the element
- They are *way* to easy to use wrong, accessing elements in an order that uses the CPU caches very poorly
- Vectors get a lot of optimization love in the CLR, there is none for multi-dimensional arrays since there is so little to gain
- And of course Array is awkward since the number of indexers is variable.

So just don't use them.  Jagged arrays and lists of lists are reasonable alternatives.  Minus the syntax sugar, arguably C# has too much of it.

Answer (score 1):

> - A few years ago, multi-dimensional arrays were much slower -- is this still the case? [Why are multi-dimensional arrays in .NET slower than normal arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468832/why-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-net-slower-than-normal-arrays)

Yes, it is. Here's a rerunning of that code with C# 5/.NET 4.5, run through LINQPad, with optimizations on.

```
sum took 00:00:01.7903305
sum took 00:00:02.9606820 (165%)
sum took 00:00:01.7093106 (95%)
```

The conclusion is somewhat subjective, but I'd agree with you that multi-dimensional arrays are second-class citizens. Jagged arrays (`double[][]`) and lists (`List<List<double>>`) appear to be the preferred approach in most cases.

And sometimes code is written with jagged or multi-dimensional arrays that never should have been like that to start with...e.g. `List<MyModel>` and `Dictionary<double, double>` might have been better choices.

Answer (score 1):

First, LINQ is designed to work with sequences. In general, one thinks of a sequence as a one-dimensional entity. So it's no surprise that it doesn't work well with multi-dimensional data types. Although LINQ probably *could* be contorted to assume row-major order and walk multi-dimensional arrays, that's not the universally accepted way of working with things. Even so, you'd then have LINQ working well with multi-dimensional arrays but not with lists of lists (i.e. `List<List<int>>`). That would open a big bag of worms. All told, you're probably better off writing your own enumerator that transforms your multi-dimensional structure to a one-dimensional sequence.

One dimensional arrays are *usually* faster than multi dimensional arrays because you have to do fewer bounds checks. This is the same reason that jagged arrays are usually faster. But that's not universally true. See my blog entry [Are jagged arrays faster than rectangular arrays?](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/05/08/are-jagged-arrays-faster-than-rectangular-arrays/).

I see no evidence that Microsoft is "pushing" us to use one dimensional arrays over multi-dimensional arrays. One dimensional arrays are simpler and therefore more easily optimized. And, since one dimensional arrays are used far more often, they're going to get more attention.

I suspect the reason that many of the `Array` class's functions don't work with multi-dimensional arrays is because they don't make sense for multiple dimensions or because they're not generally useful enough to warrant the difficulty of implementing them. I've *rarely* needed any of those functions when working with multi-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I would say no. As I am a very avid user of the Dictionary Class. And most especially dictionaries of dictionaries.

Yes it tends to run a bit slower because of the nesting and what not. But the code itself tends to be very readable and lends itself to collaboration.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't specific enough -- I'm not talking about Dictionary, List, or any of the other classes, I'm talking about the array feature of the language (maybe it's `System.Array`)